# Adding source control to my project in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I am following this tutorial in raywenderlich.com: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22590/beginning-automated-testing-with-xcode-part-12. I have problem linking my project to my repo. I have already created the repo in my github account and downloaded the starter project.

I face two problems:

1) xcode keeps asking for my password and when i enter my github account password and username, it keeps saying my authenication is wrong. its username says git always...

2) In the tutorial, to get an initial commit it says: Go to File\Source Control\Commit (⌥⌘-C) and on the following screen, enter a commit message like “initial commit” and click Commit. but when i type initial commit, the commit is not highlighted and doesn't allow me to click it.

Need some guidance to start on source control for my iOS projects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly? Don't use Xcode for that. I know I am not answering your question, but there are better ways of doing it. At the moment I am using Command Line and it's more than enough for what I do. Sometimes I use [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), but most of the times it's Command Line.

Comment: meaning to say, git init in my folder and and git clone the repo and so in the command line?

Comment: You can use this tutorial from GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo.

Comment: If you already have a repository somewhere else, git clone is enough.

Comment: Github for Mac works just as well as the command line (but it sure doesnt outright replace it).  Xcode's Git source control has never actually worked anyhow.

Comment: @CodaFi actually, sometimes, I awake up in the middle of the night with nightmares about Xcode's Source Control. :(

Comment: @JackyBoy one question: I understand create a repo using command-line. But how to link the folder to include the xcode folders and files? Need some explanation on that...

Comment: You don't. You create a git repository on the root of your project, and that's it. At the end of the day `git add -A` and then `git commit -m "My amazing commit"`and finally `git push`. You are not dependent of Xcode.

Comment: meaning to say create a folder with xcode files and the project first  before pulling it into the repo? am i right?

Comment: No @laskesh, just use command lines, go to your root folder and `git init`. If you are cloning, just `mkdir MyProject`, go inside your folder `cd MyProject` and `git clone`.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you clone your project from the github.com with the `https` link. You should choose the `git` one, something like this: `git@github.com:username/projectname.git`. Or you should refer to GitHub's help page at https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac , which tell you to install the osxkeychain credential helper.

It is written on GitHub:

The credential helper only works when you clone an HTTPS repo URL. If you use the SSH repo URL instead, SSH keys are used for authentication. [This guide](https://help.github.com/articles/ssh-key-setup) offers help generating and using an SSH key pair.

2) Have not got any good idea right now.

Comment: i did use the ssh one because the tutorial clearly stated to use the ssh version which is the git one..

Comment: Can you please use `git remote -v` to check it ?